# Using RRDtool without consolidation function

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I want to use rrdtool as a ringbuffer which simply forgets the oldest value if a new value arrives and RRA is full.
Is this even possible?

Example:

```
rrdtool create database.rrd --step 1  DS:data1:GAUGE:5:U:U RRA:<CF>:0.5:1:1200
```

After 20 min the oldest value gets replaced.

Thank you and greetings,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can render the consolodation function null by using a 1-step RRA of AVG type, as in your example.

However, what you cannot do so simply is nullify the time series and data normalisation.

Your data need to arrive exactly on a step boundary or they will be adjusted to fit to one, changing their value.  Your example uses a 1s step, which makes that much simpler; however it brings up the next problem...

RRDTool will always store a value in the RRA at each consolodated step.  If there are no data available then you will get an Unknown, or a value will be extrapolated based on previous data.  In your setup, you have an XFF=0.5 which means you'll get an unknown when no data were stored.

So, it is possible, but the RRA will ALWAYS have 1200 values in it.  If a sample did not arrive during a particular second, then an Unknown will be stored.  Samples will be dropped as soon as they are 20min old regardless of how many new samples were collected in that time window; when you query the RRA, you will get 'unknown' if nothing was collected during that second.

Whether this behaviour matches your use case requirements or not is up to you.

Comment: Okay. So I chose: "rrdtool create database.rrd --step 1  DS:data1:GAUGE:20:U:U RRA:AVERAGE:0.99:1:1200"  with a long heartbeat and big xff 99%->no unkown should be stored. The problem is: That if I populate the RRD with integers, I get floats.  I fetched the db with: "rrdtool fetch database.rrd AVERAGE" and it returns 3,8084940000e+00 for 4. Did I made something wrong. It looks like rrdtool is still consolodating the values. I push data "exactly" every second. Could that rrd calculates/relates every value over every value (step in ) in the rrd including the "nan"s. But thank you ^^

Comment: The large xff makes no odds since your RRA only contains 1pdp=1cdp -- so the proportion of unknown components is necessarily either 0% or 100%.
When you push the data,  use `rrdtool update $file.rrd $value:\`date +%s\`` so that you store it against the integer time in order to avoid data normalisation.